# Sending DOS commands using Process - missing data on OutputDataReceived callback

Tags: c#

I have been looking for a solution before posting but I gave up!
I just want to interactively send DOS command using Standard input. It works well but I always don't get the last line (the prompt line) on the OutputDataReceived callback.

Any ideas?

```
Process p = null;

    private void Start_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        p = new Process();
        p.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
        p.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
        p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
        p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
        p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        p.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";

        p.ErrorDataReceived += ErrorDataReceived;
        p.OutputDataReceived += OutputDataReceived;

        p.Start();
        p.BeginErrorReadLine();
        p.BeginOutputReadLine();

        p.StandardInput.WriteLine("dir");
    }

    private void OutputDataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.Data + "\n");
    }

    private void WriteToStandardInput_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        p.StandardInput.WriteLine(txt_command.Text); //can be "dir" or "cd temp"
    }
```

Comment: What precisely do you mean with "_prompt line_"? Do you mean the actual `D:\Some\Dir>` prompt? If so, why exactly would you need to capture this? It sounds like an XY problem to me...

Comment: Very simple. When issuing a DIR command, I am not getting the following: C:\tmp\WindowsFormsApp6\WindowsFormsApp6\bin\Debug>

Comment: 12/17/2018  02:19 PM    <DIR>          .
12/17/2018  02:19 PM    <DIR>          ..
12/17/2018  02:20 PM             9,728 WindowsFormsApp6.exe
11/22/2018  09:40 AM               189 WindowsFormsApp6.exe.config
12/17/2018  02:20 PM            28,160 WindowsFormsApp6.pdb
               3 File(s)         38,077 bytes
               2 Dir(s)  101,983,825,920 bytes free

**C:\tmp\WindowsFormsApp6\WindowsFormsApp6\bin\Debug>**

Comment: Let me repeat one of my questions: **Why** would you need to get this prompt? The current directory of cmd.exe is controlled by your application (as part of the StartInfo parameters when starting the process: `StartInfo.WorkingDirectory`), and can also be queried by using the cmd.exe command `cd` (which, if used without a directory argument, outputs the current directory cmd.exe is operating in) Also, keep in mind that the prompt is user-configurable (using the `PROMPT` environment variable) and thus could possibly look vastly different on different computers.

Comment: @elgonzo I want to get this prompt to give my winform application the look and feel of the command shell of DOS. I find it strange that all the information is coming except the last line (which is the prompt). Is there anything wrong with the code or is it the expected behavior? Another example, if you give "pause", you should get "Press any key to continue . . .", well, it doesn't come, unless you press ENTER or give another command...

Comment: Adding p.StandardInput.Close() after the writing solves it but why?

private void WriteToStandardInput_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        p.StandardInput.WriteLine(txt_command.Text); //can be "dir" or "cd temp"
 p.StandardInput.Close(); //FIXES THE LAST LINE ISSUE, BUT WHY?
}

Answer (score 0):

Adding p.StandardInput.Close() solves the problem, reason is when you close the input stream it actually terminates the process (which you start using 'p.start'). So as I said, you need start separate process for each command.

~Nilesh

Comment: Thanks, but I still dont understand why I cannot have the same behaviour of the standard CMD.exe using a C# program. When using the CMD.exe you can send multiple commands using one process.

Comment: Dir is simple command, consider a sql command terminal, here you are accepting input from user when process is running.  You execute multiple sql queries there, but process remains active.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I have found a solution... I have created 2 tasks as shown below which are reading constantly from the output and error stream and print it to a rich text box. The trick was not to use BeginErrorReadLine and BeginOutputReadLine.
I hope I was able to help others...

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private Process p = new Process();
    private SynchronizationContext context;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        context = SynchronizationContext.Current;
    }

    private void Start_Click (object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        p.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
        p.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
        p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
        p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
        p.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
        p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        p.Start();

        Task.Run(() => ReadFromStreamLoop(p.StandardOutput));
        Task.Run(() => ReadFromStreamLoop(p.StandardError));
    }

    private void ReadFromStreamLoop (StreamReader s)
    {
        int count = 0;
        char[] buffer = new char[1024];
        do
        {
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            count = s.Read(buffer, 0, 1024);
            builder.Append(buffer, 0, count);
            context.Post(new SendOrPostCallback(delegate (object state)
            {
                richTextBox1.AppendText(builder.ToString());
            }), null);
        } while (count > 0);
    }

    private void WriteToStandardInput_Click (object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        p.StandardInput.WriteLine(txt_command.Text); //can be "dir" or "cd temp"
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are looking for event end of command execution, then every time spawn a new process. At the end of processing you can show the prompt on main process. Manage your environment variable through invoking(main) process.

See the example on - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.outputdatareceived?view=netframework-4.7.2